# Collect all data from Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report containing multiple subreports. I need to find the way to 'collect' all the data printed on the report/subreports in the following (or similar)

format:

Page1:FieldName1=Value1|FieldName2=Value2|...|Page2:FieldName1=Value1.1|FieldName2=Value2.1|.....

So, the important note is that there is a possibility to figure out on which page (in the PDF generated from report) the particular field value occured.
I tried to do some complex formulas which would 'remember' all the data in a cumulative string within formula(s) (WhilePrintingRecords) but the part I can't achieve is to associate each value to correct Page number of the main, top level, report (the page numbers are of crucial importance in this purpose).
The problem is even more complex because of the groupings and linking applied in main report and subreports, so the Page numbers is at the end of the printing kinda changed comparing to design time order.

Can anyone come up with any idea please?

Comment: one approach would be in page footer along with page  number store the concatination of the values of that page in saperate formula and supress it and at the end of last  page retrive all values and display accordinig to the page number.. here you may need to create a array for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Siva for your reply! Yes, exactly, I'm updating the cumulative string on each page footer using the formula added to each subreport, and as for data, it shows up fine... but the issues related to page numbers occured after printing the whole string on the main report footer (I use shared variables, of course).

Comment: can you post screen shot of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Siva, your reply led me to another thing to investigate (I'm new to Crystal Reports) - the issue was actually not related to incorrect execution of the formula keeping the page counter, but rather the one more formula I thought was not executing, since I didn't know that if formula is in the section which is suppressed (and hidden) IS STILL EXECUTING. The counter always counted one more page which was sufficient. When I removed that formula that I didn't need - it worked just fine. So, it was my fault :(